# preg_match - если в строке присутствуют символы кроме букв то false

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как сделать preg_match что если в строке присутствуют символы кроме букв и пробела то возвращать false

по шаблону

```
^[A-zА-ЯёЁ ]
```

ну или как то так

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^[a-zа-яё ]+$/ui', 'ab c  А бв ');
```

Comment: а не так?

^ означает начало $ конец вроде как

а тут именно отрицание

preg_match('/[^a-zа-яё ]+/i', 'ab c  А бв ');

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj 
> ^ означает начало $ конец вроде как

Всё верно, и потому preg_match вернёт false, если будет всё кроме букв. 

    $subject = 'ab c  А бв ';
    /* Если false */
    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zа-яё ]+$/ui', $subject)) {
       echo 'Значение должно содержать только символы алфавита и пробел';
    }

Не забудьте использовать модификатор u, так как у Вас в строке возможно будет использоваться кириллица.

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ

Comment: а этот код будет правильно работать?

preg_match('/[^a-zа-яё ]+/i', 'ab c А бв ');

я так что то и не понял, аналог он того что вы написали или нет?

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj Да,будет,но значение будет противоположным.

    preg_match('/^[^a-zа-яё ]+$/iu', '#*_122');

выведет true,если строка не будет содержать символы алфавита и пробел.
Тогда вышеприведённое условие,будет выглядеть так:

    /* Если true */
    if (preg_match('/^[^a-zа-яё ]+$/ui', $subject)) {
       echo 'Значение должно содержать только символы алфавита и пробел';
    }
 
Символы начал и конца строки поиска (**^...$**) в паттерне обязательны.Если этого не сделать,то в массив (3 аргумент функции preg_match) попадёт часть строки удовлетворяющее этому условию,т.е. будет возвращено... --

Comment: ... true, когда это не нужно.